# Highlight Vim escape characters e.g. \n

Tags: vim, colors, escape-characters, vimrc

I'm using the [Jellybeans](https://github.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim) vim colorscheme but it doesn't highlight any escape characters. For example if I'm using C++ and have the following...

```
std::string word = "hello\n";
```

... the whole string literal will be of the same color. However I'd like to have the `\n` escape character to be a different color in the literal so it stands out more when I'm programming.

How can I go about this? Preferably I'd like to modifiy the `jellybeans.vim` color file to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By modifying the line (line 406)...

```
call s:X("Special","799d6a","","","Green","")
```

in the `jellybeans.vim` file you can change the escape character color in strings. Simply replace `799d6a` with the hex color code you want the escape character to be.